# How to edit a View hidden behind other Views in Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there an easy way in Xcode to edit a view that is hidden behind other views within the Storyboard?  I know I can hide the views in front of it and move the view to the front temporarily, but this is difficult to keep doing over and over again.  Is there a way to isolate the view somehow in Storyboard so I can edit it on its own?

Comment: In a storyboard, your subviews showed a hierarchy order. So simply drag the view to bottom which you want to edit and after edit place it back in same order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your view controller in storyboard and Open `File Inspector`

Select `Use Auto Layout` and `Use Trait Variations`

[image]

Now select the `view` you want to hide in your storyboard. Open `Attributes inspector`. Check/uncheck the `installed` option to show/hide the selected view. You can hide multiple views by changing this property after selecting all the views.

Don't forget to check this option for all the views while running the app. Else it will crash

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is an easier work-around than what I'm currently doing